# How do I replace a specific object in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of users, and I'd like to update one of those users.

```
users = [
  {userId: 23, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 34, userName:"wrong"},
  {userId: 45, userName:"baz"}
  {userId: 56, userName:"..."},
]

updatedUser = {
  userId: 34,
  userName: bar
}
```

I'm using underscorejs. I thought the simplest way is to find the index of the user to be updated, and then just set the value of that user to my updated value. Unfortunately, underscore's [indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) function doesn't accept properties, only values. To use it, I'd have to first user [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) and then pass what that returns into indexOf:

```
var valueOfUpdatedUser = _.findWhere(users, { userId: updatedUser.userId })
var indexOfUpdatedUser = _.indexOf(users, valueOfUpdatedUser)
users[indexOfUpdatedUser] = updatedUser;
```

A second approach would be to use [reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) to remove the matched user, and then push my updated user to the array.

Surely there's a better, simpler way?

Comment: You could iterate over the array yourself

Comment: You could loop over the array until you find the user. Or, use an object instead with the userId as the key.

Comment: Since an Id is by definition unique, you can create `users` as an object and use `userId` as keys. `users = { 23: { userName: 'foo' }, 34: { userName: 'wrong' }};`. That makes updating very easy: `users[34].userName = 'bar';`.

Comment: Since userId is unique I really suggest you to use hash instead of array `23: { userinfo here }, 34: { another userinfo here }`. In this case replace code will be just users[%id%] = { new info here };

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) after `findWhere`. It's not technically the same as replacing the object with another instance entirely, but it eliminates the extra loop over the array:

```
_.extend(_.findWhere(users, { userId: updatedUser.userId }), updatedUser);
```

If this is still not satisfactory then your best bet is probably to iterate manually.

I am deliberately leaving the "object properties keyed by user id" approach  out of the discussion because in practice it's not uncommon to have an array in hand to begin with (e.g. the user array was retrieved by an API).

Comment: In my case, I used "findIndex" instead of "findWhere". Maybe it's a matter of versions for the Underscore in use, but it seems to work the same way, so thank you for this info and code!! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, underscore's indexOf function doesn't accept properties, only values.

In this case, what you can use instead of indexOf is to use [findIndex](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex)

From the docs:

> Similar to _.indexOf, returns the first index where the predicate truth test passes; otherwise returns -1.

```
_.findIndex([4, 6, 8, 12], isPrime);
=> -1 // not found
_.findIndex([4, 6, 7, 12], isPrime);
=> 2
```

So in this case you'd do something like this:

```
var indexOfUpdatedUser = _.findIndex(users, { userId: updatedUser.userId });
users[indexOfUpdatedUser] = updatedUser;
```

Update: A check for a -1 value would probably be a good idea (i.e. if the index isn't found)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, it would be easier an object with ids as property names:

```
var users = {
  23: {userName: "foo"},
  34: {userName: "wrong"},
  45: {userName: "baz"},
  56: {userName: "..."}
};
```

Then, to update the data of some user, just use

```
users[updatedUserId] = updatedUserData;
```